Roblox Lua - System for grabbing ingredients and making a pizza
I have started creating a system that allows players to grab pizza ingredients from a table, and and make a pizza with them. (Currently is just dough and pepperoni). However, despite it all working, is an absolute mess and I'm unsure how to organize it. This is my first roblox game if that means anything. I understand certain concepts as I've just came from tutorial purgatory learning as much as I could, but don't know how to organize code or even the game itself. The system I've created does not make it easy to implement more ingredients and I know there is a much much better way to do this. Just not sure where to begin.
Inside ServerScriptService, I have one script:
local pizzaEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.MakePizza

local pepperoni = game.Workspace.Map.ToppingsTable.Pepperoni
local dough = game.Workspace.Map.ToppingsTable.Dough
local pizzaPlaceholder = game.Workspace.Map.Workstation.PizzaPlaceholder

-- A table that lists what toppings are on the pizza --
local pizza = {}

-- This runs if the pepperoni topping on table is clicked --
pepperoni.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    local pepperoni = game.ServerStorage.Toppings.Pepperoni
    local pepperoniClone = pepperoni:Clone()
    pepperoniClone.Parent = player.Backpack
end)

-- This runs if the dough topping on table is clicked --
dough.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    local dough = game.ServerStorage.Toppings.Dough
    local doughClone = dough:Clone()
    doughClone.Parent = player.Backpack
end)


pizzaEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    -- Checks if player his holding dough --
    if player.Character:FindFirstChild("Dough") then
        -- Removes dough from hand if used --
        local doughTool = player.Character:FindFirstChild("Dough")
        doughTool:Destroy()

        -- Creates Pizza folder that holds the pizza and ingredients in the workspace --
        local pizzaFolder = Instance.new("Folder")
        pizzaFolder.Name = "Pizza"
        pizzaFolder.Parent = game.Workspace.Map.Workstation
        
        -- Clones pizza dough from ServerStorage and replaces it with placeholder pizza --
        local newPizza = game.ServerStorage.Pizza.Dough:Clone()
        newPizza.Transparency = 0
        newPizza.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Pastel yellow")
        newPizza.Name = "PizzaInProgress"
        newPizza.Position = Vector3.new(pizzaPlaceholder.Position.X, pizzaPlaceholder.Position.Y, pizzaPlaceholder.Position.Z)
        newPizza.Parent = game.Workspace.Map.Workstation:FindFirstChild("Pizza")
        pizzaPlaceholder:Destroy()
        
        local clickDetector = Instance.new("ClickDetector")
        clickDetector.Parent = newPizza
        table.insert(pizza, "dough")
        
    -- Checks if player is holding pepperoni --
    elseif player.Character:FindFirstChild("Pepperoni") then
        -- Removes pepperoni from hand if used --
        local pepperoniTool = player.Character:FindFirstChild("Pepperoni")
        pepperoniTool:Destroy()
        
        -- Clones pepperoni from ServerStorage and puts it on pizza --
        local pepperoni = game.ServerStorage.Pizza.Pepperoni:Clone()
        local pizzaInProgress = game.Workspace.Map.Workstation:FindFirstChild("Pizza"):FindFirstChild("PizzaInProgress")
        pepperoni.Name = "Pepperoni"
        pepperoni.Position = Vector3.new(pizzaInProgress.Position.X, pizzaInProgress.Position.Y + 0.1, pizzaInProgress.Position.Z)
        pepperoni.Parent = pizzaInProgress
    end
end)

Inside ServerStorage I have the toppings that make the pizza that I can reference to clone, as well as the tools that are the topping that get put in the players backpack when clicked.
